# Renaming files with Python

Tags: python, list, rename, file-rename, renaming

A few weeks ago, I was printing "Hello, World".  Now I'm diving head-first into the coding pool and I don't know how to swim. Please throw me a life-preserver.

I have several files in a directory, such as:

> 123456 C01-1-File.pdf
>
> 123456 C02-1-File.pdf
>
> 123456 C02-2-File.pdf

And would like to remove the fixed, 6-digit prefix and add incremental prefixes, such as:

> 600 -
>
> 601 -
>
> 602 -

So, the files should be renamed to:

> 600 - C01-1-File.pdf
>
> 601 - C02-1-File.pdf
>
> 602 - C02-2-File.pdf

This is the script I have cobbled together:

```
import os
import glob
import sys

def fileRename():
    #this section determines file types to work with based on user input
    path = os.getcwd()
    a = raw_input('Enter the file extension: ')
    b = '*' + '.' + str(a)
    first_lst = sorted(glob.glob(b))
    l = len(first_lst)
    if l > 1:
        print 'There are ' + str(l) + ' files of the specified type in the current directory'
    elif l == 1:
        print 'There is ' + str(l) + ' file of the specified type in the current directory'
    else:
        print 'There are no files of the specified type in the current directory'
        sys.exit()
    for file in first_lst:
        print '\t' + file

    #this section removes a numerical prefix from specified file type
    x = raw_input('Would you like to remove the prefix from these files? [y/n]: ')
    if x == 'y':
        for filename in first_lst:
            new_filename = filename
            #while filenames in the list start with a number, remove the number
            while new_filename[0].isdigit():
                new_filename = new_filename[1:]
            #rename all files that have had the numerical prefix removed
            if new_filename != filename:
                print 'Renaming %s to %s' % (filename, new_filename)
                os.rename(os.path.join(path,filename), os.path.join(path,new_filename))

    xx = raw_input('Would you like to add an iterative prefix to these files? [y/n]: ')

    if xx == 'y':
                    second_lst = sorted(glob.glob(b))

                    #this creates an iterative list of new prefix numbers
                    x = int(raw_input('Enter the beginning prefix number: '))
                    working_lst = range(x, x + l)
                    prefix_lst = working_lst[:l]

            #this combines the prefix list and  filename list
                    final_lst = ['{} -{}'.format(x,y) for x, y in zip(prefix_lst,second_lst)]
                    for new in final_lst:
                print ('Here are the new file names: ')
                print '\t' + new

            #THIS IS THE SECTION THAT DOES NOT WORK
            #this section should rename the files with an iterative prefix
            third_lst = sorted(glob.glob(b))
                    user_input = raw_input('Would you like to continue with renaming? [y/n]: ')
                    if user_input == 'y':
                         for file in file_list:
                              print file
                         for i in final_list:
                              print i
                         print 'Renaming %s to %s' % (file, i)
    else: sys.exit()            


fileRename()
```

I've played with the syntax and indents, which produced the following results. The problem I'm having is with the output after "Would you like to continue with renaming?"


Here are some pictures that show the output:

In [attempt1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZnCk.png), only the output on the right is correct

In [attempt2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mzcQ.png), only the output on the left is correct



What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Mmh so I don't really get your problem. What exactly is wrong with your code and what do you want different in the output?

Comment: Ah now, sorry for being stupid. I understand the problem now

Comment: You have to fix indentation. It's "kaputt" and so it's not possible to understand what belongs where.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried to fix your indentation and found some design flaws on the way.

1. When removing the prefix it is possible that you are renaming all the files to the same name. That means when you e.g. have the files `1.jpg`, `2.jpg` and `3.jpg` are all renamed to `.jpg` so all the files are gone except the last one after renaming!
2. It gets really complex in your code quite fast that comes mainly from choosing poor variable names (like `x` and `xx`) and from using no helper functions. Try to write helper functions that do exactly one thing and name them wisely :)

So here is the result of the refactoring and clean up, i think it is doing (at least almost) what you want. So try to take it as a starter.

```
import glob
import sys


def fileRename():
    # this section determines file types to work with based on user input
    a = raw_input('Enter the file extension: ')
    b = '*' + '.' + str(a)
    first_lst = sorted(glob.glob(b))
    l = len(first_lst)
    if l > 1:
        print('There are ' + str(l) +
              ' files of the specified type in the current directory')
    elif l == 1:
        print('There is ' + str(l) +
              ' file of the specified type in the current directory')
    else:
        print('There are '
              'no files of the specified type in the current directory')
        sys.exit()
    for file in first_lst:
        print '\t' + file

    # this section removes a numerical prefix from specified file type
    remove_prefix = raw_input('Would you like '
                              'to remove the prefix from these files? [y/n]: ')
    new_filenames = []
    if remove_prefix == 'y':
        for filename in first_lst:
            # while filenames in the list start with a number, remove the number
            new_filename = remove_leading_number(filename)
            # rename all files that have had the numerical prefix removed
            if new_filename != filename:
                print 'Renaming %s to %s' % (filename, new_filename)
                new_filenames.append(new_filename)

    if remove_prefix == 'n':
        new_filenames = first_lst

    add_counter = raw_input('Would you like to add an '
                            'iterative prefix to these files? [y/n]: ')

    if add_counter == 'y':
        # this creates an iterative list of new prefix numbers
        prefix_num_start = int(raw_input('Enter the beginning prefix number: '))
        prefix_lst = range(prefix_num_start, prefix_num_start + l)

        # this combines the prefix list and  filename list
        final_lst = ['{}-{}'.format(x, y) for x, y in zip(prefix_lst, new_filenames)]
        for new in final_lst:
            print ('Here are the new file names: ')
            print '\t' + new

    # THIS IS THE SECTION THAT DOES NOT WORK
    # this section should rename the files with an iterative prefix
    user_input = raw_input('Would you like to continue with renaming? [y/n]: ')
    if user_input == 'y':
        for i in final_lst:
            print i
            print 'Renaming %s to %s' % (file, i)
    else:
        sys.exit()


def remove_leading_number(filename):
    while filename[0].isdigit():
        filename = filename[1:]
    return filename


fileRename()
```

Happy coding!